# Symfony 4.1 i18n route prefix: exclude route

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

**I have a i18n project running on Symfony 4.1.**

I want to achieve some routing like:

- / => a "Choose language" page route
- /fr/ or /en/ => the homepage route
- /fr/foo/, /en/bar, etc => the other routes

Following this [article](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-internationalized-routing), I'm using annotations to handle routing and I set a global prefix to my annotations routing :

```
site:
    resource: '../src/Controller/'
    type: annotation
    prefix:
        en: '/en'
        fr: '/fr'
```

This way, all the routes defined in annotations from '../src/Controller/' are prefixed, which leads to a conflict between my "Choose language" page and the homepage.

**I want to exclude the "Choose language" page from the i18n prefixing, so I'll be able to use "/" for this page, when the homepage could stay on /fr or /en.**

Any ideas to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Defining this route at top of `annotations.yaml` without prefix option:

```
_choose_language:
    path: /
    controller: App\Controller\ChooseLanguageController

site:
    resource: '../src/Controller/'
    type: annotation
    prefix:
        en: '/en'
        fr: '/fr'
```

and don't use route annotation for this special controller:

```
class ChooseLanguageController
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        return new Response('Choose Language!');
    }
}
```

then this action is being excluded from i18n prefixing.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I was looking for route options or parameters when this answer seems more logical and yet simple: it uses the Symfony route moto "the first route loaded wins".